# How To Make An Angular Directive That Calls A Function In Specific Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Product images appear within many pages of my application and I would like to design a directive to show a Modal when a visitor **clicks** any product image, regardless of where it is located within my application.

I have a Root Controller encompassing my every page of my application...

```
<section class="container" ng-controller="RootController">
    // Header
    // Body
    // Footer
</section>
```

I would like to put a `showProductModal()` function within my RootController and call it within my directive.

Lastly, I would like to pass in an object param into the `showProductModal(product)` function so that I can use it elsewhere within the scope of my RootController...

Here is what I've started with, which is just some starter code...

```
// HTML
<img src="path/to/product/image.jpg" product>

// Directive - Product Modal
app.directive("product", function() {  
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        controller: 'RootController',
        link: function(){

        };
    };
});

// Root Controller
angular.module('app').controller('RootController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.showProductPopup = function(item) {
      $scope.product  = item;
      $('#productModal').modal('show');
    };

}]);
```

Comment: What will the modal box show? Just the product image, or more? If more, then where will that data come from? Will you encode it in the HTML, or will it exist in an array somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you broadcast an event to rootScope from your directive and add a listener to your controller that triggers the modal, something like:

```
//directive
controller: function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.onClick = function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('openModal', someObjectToPopulateModal);
    }
}

//main controller
$scope.$on('openModal', function(e, someObjectToPopulateModal){
    //do something with the object you sent from the directive
    //and trigger the function that opens your modal
});
```

Comment: My (Angular) life has been changed after learning about $broadcast from your StackOverflow answer.  It's so helpful in so many ways. Thank you!